# Visual Studio 2013 Professional - Unable to find messages file 'cscui.dll'

Tags: visual-studio, dll

when I try to run any of my Projects Visual Studio says "Unable to find messages file 'cscui.dll"

But the weird thing is that I have this file in my Framework 4.0.... Folder

Does anyone know how I can fix this problem?

Comment: Your machine is pretty messed-up when you get this error.  It belongs in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\1033 and C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\1033 where 1033 is for USA English.  SO users should tell where they are from in their profile so they get better help.  Your name sounds Flemish,  1043.

Comment: @HansPassant my colleague had a corrupt cscui.dll installed.  VS only looked in the Framework path you mentioned.  Reinstalling the framework did not fix it for him.  I added a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guided by the comment on the question by @hans-passant I just stepped my colleague through this, with a new install of Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise which was just released.  We used Process Monitor with a filter on Path, of "cscui".  It came up with a `FILE_CORRUPT` entry for this dll in the `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\1033` folder.

My colleague had already attempted [the sole existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34634267/3954464) of reinstalling the .NET framework with no success.

He wasn't able to copy a correct version of the file into the `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\1033` folder due to "TrustedInstaller" related error dialogs, but Process Monitor showed that the parent directory `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319` was checked before the sub-directories, for `cscui.dll`.  So I had him copy it in there, and it fixed the problem.

It's not ideal, but for lack of the ability to do a correct fix, it solves the problem.

Answer (score -1):

you need to re install the NetFramework4.0

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). For the moment I've added the comment for you, and I'm flagging this post for deletion.